# WepAPI Method is throwing MethodNotAllowed but I don't know why

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

I think the answer is something simple, but I have a method throwing a 405 not allowed error and I'm not sure why.  Before I get into details I'll point out something that seems like a clue - the method that works is actually called Get - and I'm not sure if there is some HTTP method mapping done behind the scenes that causes that to work.

I have a controller with multiple methods in it.  So far I'm testing 2 of them and the first one works just fine, yet the second is throwing the error.

My controller is OOB setup, my logic and model are in separate projects.  The following method is called and returns correctly:

```
[Route("api/GetFastPlan/{key}/{clientID}/{fastPlanID}")]
public RequestFastPlanResult Get(string key, string clientID, int fastPlanID)
{
    return new FastPlanFileShare().RequestFastPlan(key, clientID, fastPlanID);
}
```

This method however is throwing a 405.

```
[Route("api/UpdateDownloads/{key}/{clientID}/{fastPlanID}")]
public UpdateDownloadsResult UpdateDownloads(string key
   , string clientID, int fastPlanID)
{
     return new FastPlanFileShare().UpdateNumberOfDownloadsColumnFastPlan(key
    , clientID, fastPlanID);
}
```

I am calling them both with the same code setup, which is here in my test project:

```
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
    httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:8129/api/UpdateDownloads/value1/value2/1082");

    HttpResponseMessage response = httpClient.GetAsync("http://localhost:8129/api/UpdateDownloads/value1/value2/1082").Result;

     Assert.IsTrue(response.IsSuccessStatusCode);

     if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
     {
        var rp = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<ServiceReference2.RequestFastPlanResult>();

        Assert.IsTrue(rp.Result.ServiceResult.WasSuccessful);
     }
}
```

full error:

> {StatusCode: 405, ReasonPhrase: 'Method Not Allowed', Version: 1.1,
>   Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers: {   Pragma: no-cache 
>   X-SourceFiles:
>   =?UTF-8?B?RDpcUHJvamVjdHNcTkVUMjAxK1xFeWVNRCBFTVIgSW50ZXJuYWwgV2Vic2VydmljZXNcRU1SU2VydmljZXMuV2ViQVBJXGFwaVxVcGRhdGVEb3dubG9hZHNcZXllbWRlbXIjMVxFWUU5ODQ1NFwxMDgy?=
>   Cache-Control: no-cache   Date: Wed, 06 Jan 2016 13:50:43 GMT
>   Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0   X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
>   X-Powered-By: ASP.NET   Content-Length: 72   Allow: POST
>   Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8   Expires: -1 }}

Comment: If you read the error, it says "Allow POST" but you're doing a GET. Change one or the other so that they match.

Comment: Thanks, I added [HTTPGet] on the controller method and it worked.  Did it default to a POST or how did it get set to POST - if you know off hand.

Comment: @AdamHeeg, unfortunately I can't find a page stating this, but it's due to your method starting with "Update". WebApi assumes a POST action if you don't tell it otherwise. I think it will make similar assumptions if you start your method name with Get, Post, Put, Delete, or Create. There may be others.